# How to get logged in user ID and pass to backend or set via backend. Djano, DRF, Vue.js, Djoser

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

So when a user submits a form via frontend (Vue.js), I want to be able to set the `created_by` attribute in the backend. What is the best way of achieving this?

**Views**

```
class ProjectView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Project.objects.order_by('-created_at')

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = ProjectsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            serializer = ProjectsSerializer
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

**Serializer**

```
class ProjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    interest_category = serializers.StringRelatedField()
   
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            'project_title',
            'project_description',
            'interest_category',
            'created_by',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        )
```

**The data I am passing from Frontend**

```
project_title: this.project_title,
project_description: this.project_description,
interest_category: this.interest_category,
```

I do have a token saved in localStorage, but I do not know how to get the ID of the currently logged in user id and pass to backend or set in backend. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

**What is the best way of setting `created_by` the submitting/requesting user in the backend?**

Answer (score 0):

DRF does the work for you, assuming you are using Cookie auth or token auth you can retrieve the user by overriding the get_object :

```
def get_object(self):
  queryset = self.get_queryset()
  obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, user=self.request.user)
  return obj
```

https://www.cdrf.co/3.13/rest_framework.generics/RetrieveAPIView.html#get_object